# How to create TreeMap variable for JSP, so I can iterate over it using JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I just started using JSP and JSTL and I'm pretty confused about the logic of how to use JSTL tags and how to create variables with JSTL.

This is my JSP page.

I am trying to iterate over Treemap and display key and value on my JSP page.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page import="com.company.ClassWhereMapIs" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Map" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.TreeMap" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Keys and values from TreeMap.</h1>

        <c:forEach var="entry" items="${treeMap}">
            Key: <c:out value="${entry.key}"/>
            Value: <c:out value="${entry.value}"/>
        </c:forEach>


    </body>
</html>
```

How do I create variable ${treeMap} ?

Best if you could show the full example.

Please help!

Comment: Ok, maybe my question wasn't clear. I have simple java Class (ClassWhereMapIs) that holds a TreeMap with values. Now I want to access this class and get the TreeMap variable and show each key and value on my JSP page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP / JSTL are technologies used for the **view** of your application. The view's job is to generate an HTML page from data (the **model**: Java beans) prepared and passed to the view by a Java class: the **controller**.

The controller is typically implemented as a Servlet.

To pass data to the view, the controller does the following:

```
SomeData data = ...;
request.setAttribute("data", data);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/the/path/of/the/view.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Since the controller has stored the data to display in a request attribute (named "data" in my example), the JSTL can now access this object:

```
<ul>
    <c:forEach var="product" items="${data.products}">
        <li><c:out value="${product.name}"/></li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

So, to answer your question briefly, the JSP EL "variables" are in fact page, request (most of the time), session or application attributes, and these attributes are usually created and stored by a Java controller, before the JSP is executed.

This MVC pattern is simpler to implement, and offers much more features, if you use a real MVC framework like Spring MVC.